# reverse string code returns error when 1 character is entered

Tags: java, string

I wrote this java program that reverses a string that is entered, but when I only enter 1 character for example "a" is bombs out, I can not figure out why.
Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program5_JohnHuber
{
public static void main(String reverseStyle[])
{

Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("\nEnter the string: ");
String stringtoReverse;
stringtoReverse=input.nextLine();

String firstchar=stringtoReverse.substring(0, 1);
String strReverse=ReverseString(stringtoReverse.substring(1));
strReverse=strReverse+firstchar;

System.out.println("\nThe reversed string is: "+ strReverse);
}

public static String ReverseString(String str)
{
String strReverse = "";

if(str.length() == 1)
    {
    return str;
    }
else
    {
    strReverse += str.charAt(str.length()-1) + 
ReverseString(str.substring(0,str.length()-1));
    return strReverse;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered debugging your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a base case to your `ReverseString()` method which just returns empty string if the input itself be empty string:

```
public static String ReverseString(String str) {
    String strReverse = "";
    if ("".equals(str)) {
        return strReverse;
    }

    if (str.length() == 1) {
        return str;
    }
    else {
        strReverse += str.charAt(str.length()-1) +
            ReverseString(str.substring(0,str.length()-1));
        return strReverse;
    }
}
```

The reason this should work is that in the case of a single character you were passing empty string to the reverse method which was then trying to traverse that string.

Actually, you don't even need to substring off the first character at this point, just pass any string, including empty string, to `ReverseString()` and it should work.  Check the demo below.

## Demo

Answer (score 0):

if you observe your code, the string reversal is well handled in your ReverseString method.. you are mishandling it in main for handling first character.. problem is when only one char in string.. substring(1) gives an exception

uncomment these two lines like below..

```
//String firstchar=stringtoReverse.substring(0, 1);
String strReverse=ReverseString(stringtoReverse.substring(1));
//strReverse=strReverse+firstchar;
```